# R/C++ Interface

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, r

How to use RCPP_MODULE(yada) in C++.
My C++ program gives error if I use

```
const char* hello( std::string who ){
std::string result( "hello " ) ;
result += who ;
return result.c_str() ;
}

RCPP_MODULE(yada)
{
using namespace std;
function( "hello", &hello ) ;
};
```

Error are:
1. Error 1 error C2065: 'yada' : undeclared identifier
2. Error 2 error C2448: 'RCPP_MODULE' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition

Can anyone help me in fixing these error?

Comment: What is `RCPP_MODULE`? Should I know it?

Comment: I think it's an "R to CPP"  thing. http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html

Comment: Cross posting: http://www.wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?catid=10&threadid=78305

Answer (score 3):

Rcpp does not work with Visual Studio, see Question 2.7 in [Rcpp FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The point of `RCPP_MODULE` is to **expose C++ to R**.

You need to include `R.h` and `Rdefines.h` and state `using namespace Rcpp;`

Comment: There is no r.h and Rdefines.h library.

Comment: When I include R.h, Rdefines.H and using namespace Rcpp I get error. 

For using namespace error is : Error: unexpected symbol in " using namespace"