# Locating/downloading header files R.h and Rmath for C interfacing with R

Tags: c++, c, r, header-files

There are a number of similar questions on this matter, but none seem to tell me exactly where to get the R.h and Rmath.h header files if I don't already have them (I have searched my computer and they aren't there).  These are the headers necessary for linking C/ C++ functions with R code.

Put simply, which R package should put the headers on the computer, or is there a website I could download them from?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128078/how-to-install-locate-r-h-and-rmath-h-head-files) mentions the R-devel package, but that does not seem to be available to me in my version of R (3.1.1).  Other questions on Stack Overflow found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961247/r-h-and-rmath-h-in-native-c-program), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181927/linking-r-h-rembedded-h-with-c-code/19182160#19182160), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281737/r-c-interface/3283529#3283529), but not directly answering the question I don't think.

Any help appreciated.

Christopher

Comment: What OS? What version?

Comment: What operating system are you on? Have you installed R from binaries or source? "R-devel" is not an R package but the development version of R - that question refers to it as an operating system (yum) package.

Comment: R-devel may be the package name for some poor distribution.

Comment: Windows 7.  I'm afraid I don't know the difference between installing from binaries or source, but I installed from [The R website](http://www.r-project.org/).

Comment: You installed a binary.  But `R CMD config --cppflags` (as per my answer) should still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be in the `include` folder below R's `RHOME` folder.

```
$ R RHOME
/home/rowlings/Downloads/R-3.2.1

$ ls -l `R RHOME`/include
total 108
-rw-r--r-- 1 rowlings rowlings   511 Jun 29 17:34 Rconfig.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 rowlings rowlings  5916 Jun 29 17:34 Rdefines.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 rowlings rowlings  2085 Jun 29 17:34 Rembedded.h
drwxr-xr-x 2 rowlings rowlings  4096 Jun 29 17:34 R_ext
-rw-r--r-- 1 rowlings rowlings  2063 Jun 29 17:34 R.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 rowlings rowlings  4818 Jun 29 17:34 Rinterface.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 rowlings rowlings 46137 Jun 29 17:34 Rinternals.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 rowlings rowlings 17619 Jun 29 17:34 Rmath.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 rowlings rowlings   509 Jun 29 17:34 Rversion.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 rowlings rowlings  2142 Jun 29 17:34 S.h
```

Comment: Thanks - I did actually find them there.  The default directory for the header files seemed to be somewhere in RBuildTools where I was looking, and my automatic searches of the system apparently didn't search the R program files (although it did search RBuildTools because it found other header files there).  I've copied them across now.  Currently having trouble with R CMD SHLIB - does anybody know what status 127 means?

Answer (score 2):

Most Linux distros should have `locate`:

```
edd@max:~$ locate Rmath.h | grep "usr/" | grep -v "local/"
/usr/include/Rmath.h
/usr/include/JAGS/JRmath.h
/usr/share/R/include/Rmath.h
edd@max:~$
```

(I have dev versions here, version control checkouts and the sources for the Debian packages hence the `grep`. Also shows one false positive from JAGS.)

Finally, the "official" way to go about this is to ask R itself:

```
edd@max:~$ R CMD config --cppflags
-I/usr/share/R/include
edd@max:~$
```

Comment: I get "R was not built as a library" :(

Answer (score 0):

You can get the code form this link  -

Rmath.h
https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/cxxr/doc/html/Rmath_8h_source.html

R.h-
https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/cxxr/doc/html/R_8h_source.html

Comment: They do seem to be the codes for C++ and R integration.  The trouble is I note that R.h requires a lot of sub-headers (so to speak) as well.

Answer (score 0):

These headers are included with R installations (whether from CRAN or built from source); you should be able to find them using `R.home()` in an R session; e.g.

```
list.files(R.home("include"))
```

gives me

```
> list.files(R.home("include"))
 [1] "libintl.h"    "R_ext"        "R.h"         
 [4] "Rconfig.h"    "Rdefines.h"   "Rembedded.h" 
 [7] "Rinterface.h" "Rinternals.h" "Rmath.h"     
[10] "Rversion.h"   "S.h"
```